# Run MS Flow on SharePoint 2016 on premise

Tags: ms-flow

I'm looking to configure MS Flow on my SharePoint 2016 on premise version. 
Is it feasible to configure flow on 2016 On-premise ? If yes, please suggest how can I approach to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible through the **Data GetWay** connection. Below are the steps we need to follow to set up the environment :

1. Install the Data GateWay on a machine which is not an AD and which is running always. If the data gateway machine is switched off, then the flow will fail.

Install the **Data GateWay**  from [here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premises-data-gateway/)  ,installation steps are mentioned there.

2. Create a connection
3. Add a Data Source.

Note :

- It needs minimum p1 license type

For details steps follow the below article :

[How To Use The SharePoint 2016 On Premise Data In Microsoft Flow Using On Prem Data GateWay Connection](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-2016-on-premise-data-in-microsoft-flow-using-on-prem-data-gateway-connection/)

Answer (score 0):

The on-premesis data gateway achieves this but requires a few things:

1. Flow P1 licensing, at a minimum
2. The gateway must be part of the Active Directory forest.
3. One or more gateways (you can have an active/active configuration) should be deployed to Windows Servers. Leave the gateway running under the account created by the gateway.
4. When you create an Action or Trigger, add your credential but specify the gateway to use. Use UPN or domain\samAccountName format for any connections.

The gateway itself needs no open inbound ports, though does require outbound connectivity to connect to the cloud.

It should be noted that with SharePoint Server 2016, not all column types are supported, for example Choice columns are not visible in Flows -- if you needed data from a Choice column, you would need a standard SharePoint workflow to copy that data to a text field, for example.

Here are some official sources of information:

[Install an on-premises data gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install)

[On-premises data gateway download](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53127)